# is it more efficient to cache a dataframe in on partition or more partitions

Tags: apache-spark, caching

I'm persisting a dataFrame, and in the spark interface i see that this dataframe is partitioned in my 7 nodes.

My spark job have transformations with wide dependencies.
Could it be more performant to force the cache in only 1 partition ?
To avoid shuffle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a balance between number of partitions and therefore concurrency. Dare I say it, you are a little off-beam here. Meaning:

- Too much partitioning makes no sense --> too much overhead.
- Just one partition would mean a coalesce or re-partition and would lack parallel processing of what Spark offers to get the job done quicker, e.g. many workers in parallel loading supermarket shelves is faster than just you and I doing it on our own.
- The truth is somewhere in between in terms of number of partitions which at scale needs to be estimated and trialled, and, shuffling can rarely be avoided unless you base the partitioning on what you read in from HDFS/Hadoop Source (e.g. KUDU) or S3, or from JDBC.